# How do I merge %denelli-0[1-5]d\.example\.com to an existing bash code e.g HOST=%denelli-0[1-5]p\.example\.com so it appears as one line only?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How do I merge %denelli-0[1-5]d.example.com to an existing bash code e.g HOST=%denelli-0[1-5]p.example.com so it appears as one line only?

In this list of hosts, the p stands for PROD and the d stands for DEV.

I need to harmonize both the DEV and PROD servers on same code but I tried HOST=%denelli-0[1-5][dp].example.com on my code but it had an error still.

How can I get this to include all the list of servers on the DEV and PROD environment?

I tried HOST=%denelli-0[1-5][dp].example.com on my code but it had an error still.

How can I get this to include all the list of servers on the DEV and PROD environment?

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate strings like `"%denelli-0[1-5]d.example.com"` and save them in the variable *HOST*? Are *p* and *d* variables too? How should the end result look like? Please EDIT your question if you add additional info.

Comment: An example of one of the servers in this string is denelli-01d.example.com (where this d symbolises DEV) and also denelli-01p.example.com (where the p symbolises PROD).

Comment: Did my example above help in writing these in a single string.

Comment: I think you have to clarify what you want as a result and give all variables necessary to achieve that (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise ppl gonna vote to close because of clarity. My guess is you want some sort of parameter expansion.